# Is there any limit for MySQL database rows

Tags: mysql-5.5, php

1. I'm creating a database website which has a lot of
   data (Username,name,address,posts etc).
2. Is there any limit to store database rows? (I have a table with more
   than 100,000 rows)
3. How to host this website (will a simple hosting will do or should I
   buy a server for hosting this website only)?
4. How the hosting RAM speed works with database fetch?

I'm a kid in database applications. I have done lot of websites with small databases and I use hosting like godaddy, hostso etc.

Comment: 1 lakh = 100,000. You should be aware that not everyone is familiar with units from South Asia. 100,000 rows is very small these days. As to your hosting, only you can answer that - traffic volume, convenience, cost &c. You will also need to test your application and see if your RAM is sufficient, but as I said, 100,000 rows (if that's your biggest table) is a small table.

Comment: @Vérace So there is no limit in mysql rows ? Im using php language. Didnt mention in my question.1 more thing , Whats the difference between virtual private server and dedicated server

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-size-limit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html